# Soft Real Time Linux Scheduling

Tags: c, linux, embedded, real-time, rtos

I have a project with some soft real-time requirements.  I have two processes (programs that I've written) that do some data acquisition.  In either case, I need to continuously read in data that's coming in and process it.

The first program is heavily threaded, and the second one uses a library which *should* be threaded, but I have no clue what's going on under the hood.  Each program is executed by the user and (by default) I see each with a priority of 20 and a nice value of 0.  Each program uses roughly 30% of the CPU.

As it stands, both processes have to contended with a few background processes, and I want to give my two programs the best shot at the CPU as possible.  My main issue is that I have a device that I talk to that has a 64 byte hardware buffer, and if I don't read from it in time, I get an overflow.  I have noted this condition occurring once every 2-3 hours of run time.

Based on my research (http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html) there appear to be three ways of playing around with the priority:

1. Set the nice value to a lower number, and therefore give each process more priority.  I can do this without any modification to my code (or use the system call) using the nice command.
2. Use sched_setscheduler() for the entire process to a particular scheduling policy.
3. Use pthread_setschedparam() to individually set each pthread.

I have run into the following roadblocks:

1. Say I go with choice 3, how do I prevent lower priority threads from being starved?  Is there also a way to ensure that shared locks cause lower priority threads to be promoted to a higher priority?  Say I have a thread that's real-time, SCHED_RR and it shared a lock with a default, SCHED_OTHER thread.  When the SCHED_OTHER thread gets the lock, I want it to execute @ higher priority to free the lock.  How do I ensure this?
2. If a thread of SCHED_RR creates another thread, is the new thread automatically SCHED_RR, or do I need to specify this?  What if I have a process that I have set to SCHED_RR, do all its threads automatically follow this policy?  What if a process of SCHED_RR spawns a child process, is it too automatically SCHED_RR?
3. Does any of this matter given that the code only uses up 60% of the CPU?  Or are there still issues with the CPU being shared with background processes that I should be concerned with and could be caused my buffer overflows?

Sorry for the long winded question, but I felt it needed some background info.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The 64 byte hardware buffer should not matter because the driver should have much more buffer space than that.  How are you communicating with the driver?

Comment: The chip itself is an i2c to uart bridge, and will only hold 64 bytes of UART data.  Currently I am continously polling the chip by opening the /dev/i2c file.  As far as I know, there is not a better driver available and I'm under a time crunch and won't have the time to put something better together.

Comment: A highest-priority blocking read is not quick enough?

Comment: For the 99% case it is, but I get 1 FIFO overflow every couple of hours.  I've actually increased the nice level of my program to -20 and I haven't seen an issue yet, but more testing might be required.  I know that I'm doing the I/O equivalent of trying to cure a brain tumor with some pain killers, but it looks like it did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) [pthread_mutex_setprioceiling](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/pthread_mutex_getprioceiling.html)

(2) A newly created thread inherits the schedule and priority of its creating thread unless it's thread attributes (e.g. [pthread_attr_setschedparam](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_attr_getschedparam.html) / [pthread_attr_setschedpolicy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_attr_getschedpolicy.html)) are directed to do otherwise when you call `pthread_create`.

(3) Since you don't know what causes it now it is in fairness hard for anyone say with assurance.